# c++11 regex : check if a set of characters exist in a string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

If for example, I have the string: "asdf{ asdf }",

I want to check if the string contains any character in the set `[]{}()`.

How would I go about doing this?

I'm looking for a general solution that checks if the string has the characters in the set, so that I can continue to add lookup characters in the set in the future.

Comment: `std::string::find_first_of`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear on whether you only want to detect if any of the characters in the search set are present in the input string, or whether you want to find all matches.

In either case, use `std::regex` to create the regular expression object. Because all the characters in your search set have special meanings in regular expressions, you'll need to escape all of them.

```
std::regex r{R"([\[\]\{\}\(\)])"};
char const *str = "asdf{ asdf }";
```

If you want to only detect whether at least one match was found, use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

```
std::cmatch results;

if(std::regex_search(str, results, r)) {
    std::cout << "match found\n";
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to find all the matches, use [`std::regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

```
std::cmatch results;

auto first = std::cregex_iterator(str, str + std::strlen(str), r);
auto last = std::cregex_iterator();

if(first != last) std::cout << "match found\n";
while(first != last) {
    std::cout << (*first++).str() << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a882168c7a312255)

Comment: And you can use `std::distance(first,last)` to obtain the count of matches and, these methods are in the `regex` library

Comment: @user3791372 Yes, you can use `std::distance` to find the number of matches, but you should also be aware that `std::regex_iterator` is a ForwardIterator, so `distance` will have linear complexity (although that's unlikely to be an issue for most use cases).

Comment: @Praetorian I was referring to the first situation, but nice answer including both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about regex but this specific problem can be solved without it using std::string::find_first_of() which finds the position of the first character in the string(s) that is contained in a set (g):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "asdf{ asdf }";
    std::string g = "[]{}()";

    // Does the string contain one of thecharacters?
    if(s.find_first_of(g) != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << s << " contains one of " << g << '\n';

    // find the position of each occurence of the characters in the string
    for(size_t pos = 0; (pos = s.find_first_of(g, pos)) != std::string::npos; ++pos)
        std::cout << s << " contains " << s[pos] << " at " << pos << '\n';
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
asdf{ asdf } contains one of []{}()
asdf{ asdf } contains { at 4
asdf{ asdf } contains } at 11
```